# Wald Test Statistic for an M-estimator

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wald-test, m-estimation, quasi-maximum-likelihood

Suppose we are interested in the following hypothesis:
$$H_0: h(\theta)=0\quad versus\quad h(\theta)\neq 0,$$
and we have an usual M-estimator for $\theta$ such that
$$\sqrt{N}(\widehat{\theta} -\theta) \xrightarrow{\quad d\quad} N(0,A^{-1}BA^{-1}),$$
where $A$ and $B$ are the second and first derivative of the objective function of $\hat{\theta}$, respectively.

Here, by the $\delta$-method, we can derive that
$$\sqrt{N}(h(\hat{\theta})-h(\theta)) \xrightarrow{\quad d\quad}N(0,\;h_{\theta'}(A^{-1}BA^{-1})h_{\theta}),$$
where $h_\theta=\frac{\partial h(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ and $h_{\theta'}=(h_{\theta})'$.

**Then, I think, the Wald test statistic should be**
\begin{align}
W=h(\hat{\theta})'\left[N^{-1}\hat{h}_{\theta'}(\hat{A}^{-1}\hat{B}\hat{A}^{-1})\hat{h}_{\theta}\right]^{-1}h(\hat{\theta})
\end{align}
where $\hat{h}_{\theta},\;\hat{A},\;\textrm{and}\;\hat{B}$ are proper estimators for $h_{\theta},\;A,\;\textrm{and}\;B$, respectively.

However, in a textbook (Cameron, A. C., & Trivedi, P. K. (2005). Microeconometrics: methods and applications. Cambridge university press.) (244p), the test statistic is slightly different.

**To be specific, in the book, the Wald test statistic is**
\begin{align}
\tilde{W}=h(\hat{\theta})'\left[N^{-1}\hat{R}(\hat{A}^{-1}\hat{B}\hat{A}^{-1})\hat{R}'\right]^{-1}h(\hat{\theta})
\end{align}
where $R=\frac{\partial\,\ln\,h(\theta)}{\partial \theta'}$ and $\hat{R}$ is the corresponding estimator.

That is, the difference between the test statistics $W$ and $\tilde{W}$ are $h_{\theta}$ and $R$ terms.

**I am pretty sure that the statistic $W$ is correct. But, I also believe the text book.
So, which of the two is correct?**